# Why does setInterval not prevent stack overflow

Tags: javascript, recursion, logic, setinterval

I have this piece of code in javascript which I believe should not lead to stack overflow but it does, because in setInterval, I introduce a statement to stop infinite recursion of another function

```
let setval = false;
let ctr = 0;

let f = function() {
    ctr++;
    if (setval == true) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        f();
    }
}
setTimeout(() => {
    setval = true;
}, 1);
f();
```

why does it behave this way? In 1 ms surely there cannot be 13985 calls to `f()`, which is the value of `ctr`.

Comment: Any queued tasks set via `setTimeout` will be executed *if and when the current execution has finished.* Which yours never does.

Comment: Javascript is not preemptive. `setTimeout`'s function won't run until `f()` completes (which never happens normally).

Comment: " In 1 ms surely there cannot be 13985 calls to f()" Why not? Modern computers process *billions* of CPU instructions per second. Calling a function doesn't take all that many instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript execution model is based on event loop. Read more about this model @ below MDN documentation site.

[JavaScript Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Unless the main stack gets free, the queued execution would never be called. This makes the interval method to wait in queue, until the execution of `f()` gets completed, which does not occur with above code snippet.

[image: JavaScript Event Loop]